# How do you downgrade pyinstaller using pip?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, exe, pyinstaller, downgrade

I am currently developing a program in python and I am converting this into a .exe file so I can share it. However, there have been many virus alerts and I have not been able to do this. I am using PyInstaller to convert my files. I believe this issue may be coming from the actual conversion itself. I have heard that the new version of PyInstaller is generating these issues. Many people have said to downgrade PyInstaller to an earlier version to avoid this issue.

So my question is: 'How do you downgrade a python module such as PyInstaller?'

And should I try using other modules to convert my files or should I stick to PyInstaller?

Thanks!

Comment: Install a specific version: `python -m pip install PyInstaller==X.Y.Z`.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to install it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `pip install pyinstaller==3.6`? In this case, I have chosen the version 3.6. You can choose other versions also.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install --upgrade (package)==(version)
```

Add this command instead of (package) write your package which here you want pyinstaller and then in (version) add which version you want to of the pyinstaller.

MAKE SURE TO REMOVE THE BRACES ().